# how to install latest git using apt-get?

Tags: git, ubuntu, apt

I installed git using `sudo apt upgrade git` but it only installed 1.9.1 version even though the latest git available is 2.11.0.

When I tried running apt-cache policy git, I got the following

```
$apt-cache policy git
git:
  Installed: 1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.3
  Candidate: 1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.3
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:1.9.1-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: When you say "latest git available is 2.11.0" what exactly do you base that claim on?

Comment: I might be looking at the wrong place but I got that info from https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: So the problem is you're looking at a list maintained by Git people, but installing packages from a service maintained by Apt people.  These two are not always in sync.  The very latest versions of things are not always in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am not aware of the PPA's

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Just try it:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I am using 16.04 LTS and have tried to update from git 2.7.4 to 2.14x. I get the following message: git is already the newest version (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.2).